# Comment section appearing over right hand side of all posts

Tags: posts

In the past few days, after navigating to my site (Chemiotics II) a few seconds later comments made to earlier posts appear on the right half hiding the underlying post material.  How can I stop this?

Comment: This could be something to do with your theme or a plugin. You'll have to narrow down the issue -- try switching to a different theme and/or turning off all plugins, then re-activating them one by one till the issue recurs. Then contact the offending theme or plugin's support team for assistance.